# Running time function for an algorithm with while and for loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have trouble determining the running time function for algorithm below. I know that there are initially two assignment operations, `int i=n` and `int s=0`.

Also, I know that the *while loop* is represented by $\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor + 1$, but the *for loop* depends on the value of $i$ which decrements by half.

So, the first time the for loop performs $n$ times, the second time the for loop performs $n/2$ times, and so on. How can I represent this behavior?

I suppose that, at the end, the result is the product of both behaviors.

```
int i = n; int s = 0; 
while(i > 0) { 
    for(j = 1; j <= i; ++j) s++; 
    i /= 2;
}
```

Comment: " the while loop is represented by ..." -- that statement does not make too much sense. "at the end, the result is the product of both behaviors" -- not quite, except in simple cases. See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) on how to analyse such things; you can also search [tag:runtime-analysis+loops].

Answer (score 2):

For each value of $i$, the inner loop runs $i$ times, and so the running time of the body of the outer loop with a given value `i` is in $\Theta(i)$. The values of `i`, as you mention, are $n, \lfloor n/2 \rfloor, \lfloor n/4 \rfloor, \cdots, 1$, and so the overall running time is
$$ \Theta(n + n/2 + n/4 + \cdots + 1) = \Theta(n). $$
Here we use the fact that the infinite series $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + \cdots$ converges (to $2$).